# If there are $3$ bags each containing $2$ balls, in how many ways exactly three $3$ balls can be selected from them?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If there are $3$ bags each containing $2$ balls, then in how many ways exactly three $3$ balls can be selected from them?

My approach: $a+b+c=3$ where $0\leq a\leq2$, $0\leq b\leq2$, $0\leq b\leq2$, so I can rewrite the equation to $(2-a)+(2-b)+(2-c)=3\ \implies\ a+b+c =3$. Now on applying bars and stars method total possible combinations can be $_5C_2$ that is equal to $10$ but there are only $7$ solutions in this case $(2~1~0)(1~2~0)(0~2~1)(0~1~2)(2~0~1)(1~0~2)(1~1~1)$. What I am doing wrong?

Bags are distinguishable and balls are not.

Comment: What about the constraint? You might want to use Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

Comment: @Azlif can you please explain with the help of an example?

Comment: $a + b + c = 3$ has $10$ solution, but including $(a,b,c) = (3,0,0),(0,3,0),(0,0,3)$

Comment: You have not taken into account that the balls are different.  Any time you select one ball from a bag, you have two options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : Calculate when there is no constraint and when one of $a,b,c$ is larger than $2$ (that is, one of $a,b,c$ is $3$, there are 3 cases) then use Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

Comment: But i have already taken care of constraints `(2−a)+(2−b)+(2−c)=3`

Comment: there is still the constraint. If You substitute $a' = 2 - a$ and for the other, then $0 \leq a \leq 2$ the same constraint from the first.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There are 8 ways to choose {1.1.1}

you take one way !!

This may be useful 
$${2\choose 1}*{2\choose1}*{2\choose1}+3!*{2\choose2}*{2\choose1}*{2\choose0}$$
$$2*2*2+6*1*2*1=8+12=20$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.